# docker service dead after reboot on Ubuntu VM

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04, systemd, systemctl

Every time I reboot my VM I have to manually start docker using:

```
systemctl start docker
```

I have the service enabled, and still for some reason it doesn't work.

```
systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com

Jan 29 16:08:25 <HOSTNAME> systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.
Jan 29 16:08:25 <HOSTNAME> systemd[1]: docker.service: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

docker version info:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.2
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        2291f61
 Built:             Mon Dec 28 16:17:32 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.11
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.10
  Git commit:       42e35e61f3
  Built:            Mon Jun  1 09:10:54 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

after looking at systemctl list-dependencies docker. On reboot docker.socket fails.

```
`
● docker.socket - Docker Socket for the API
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Fri 2021-01-29 16:32:47 UTC; 2min 3s ago
   Listen: /var/run/docker.sock (Stream)
Jan 29 16:29:46 <HOST> systemd[1]: Starting Docker Socket for the API.
Jan 29 16:31:16 <HOST> systemd[1]: docker.socket: Starting timed out. Stopping.
Jan 29 16:31:16 <HOST> systemd[990]: docker.socket: Failed to resolve group docker: Connection refused
```

Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: what version of docker do you use?

Comment: just updated the post with the info. Thanks.

Comment: Check depdencies `systemctl list-dependencies --reverse docker.service` , also can try `systemctl show docker` to see all the information

Comment: Thanks. It is failing because docker.socket failed. I updated to original post to with the docker.socket erro.

Answer (score 0):

It says:

```
Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Use `systemctl list-dependencies docker` to see what it depends on, and what state those dependencies are in.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated the post with the docker.socket error. On reboot docker.socket fails.